# How do i make my string work inside of the switch in this program?

Tags: c, logic

I am trying to make a code that does pick an int number or an char, inside on a string and display latter my options of age range if my input is an char bettewen A and D, and the class if i pick an age. I was inserting all in one big switch case but when i get to the "case 10:" simple the input dosent work, and i dont seen to make it work.
the code in question:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    
    char resp[300];
    
    printf ("Inform the letter of the class\nOr the age of the student\n");
    scanf (" %s", &resp[300]);
    
    switch (resp[300]){
        
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
        printf ("\nFor students in the class A\nThe age range is between 4~5 years.");
        break;
        
        case 'b':
        case 'B':
        printf ("\nFor students in the class B\nThe age range is between 6~8 years.");
        break;
        
        case 'c':
        case 'C':
        printf ("\nFor students in the class C\nThe age range is between 9~10 years.");
        break;
        
        case '4' ... '5':
        printf ("\nFor the students in the age %s\nThe class will be A.", resp);   
        break;
        
        case '6' ... '8':
        printf ("\nFor the students in the age %s\nThe class will be B.", resp);
        break;
        
        case '9':
        case 10:
        printf ("\nFor the students in the age %s\nThe class will be C.", resp);
        break;
        
        default:
        printf ("\nWe are out of class\nFor students below 4 yo\nOr more than 10yo.");
        break;
        
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

When we get to the value 10 the code simple ignores this case and end the program, and the program does nott proper display the strings in the cases bettwen 4-9, is there any way to make any of this work with the switch?

I try to make an condition for to it to convert if the value was 10 this way:

```
if (resp[300] == "10"){
resp [300] = x;}
```

and switch the `case "10":` for `case 'x':`.
but this does not seen to make things work.

Comment: resp[300] is out of bounds. You need to use string functions to compare and assign to strings.

Comment: `case '4' ... '5':` there is no case with intervals in C. You need to enumerate all cases individually.

Comment: You can't switch on a string, only on an integer.  Such as *one character* of your string, for example.

Comment: Also `scanf (" %s", &resp[300]);` -> `scanf (" %s", resp);`. And probably `if (resp[300] == "10")` -> `if (strcmp(resp, "10") == 0)`, but `resp [300] = x;`  doesn't make much sense, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `char resp[300];` Is how you *declare* `resp` as an array of 300 `char`.  To refer to it elsewhere, you just use its name, `resp`.

Answer (score 4):

```
char resp[300];
```

This declares a char array of 300 elements. As a string needs to be zero-terminated, this can hold up to 299 characters.

```
scanf (" %s", &resp[300]);
```

This should read `scanf( " %s", resp )`. Or, better, `scanf( " %299s", resp )`, to avoid overflow.

You should **ALWAYS** check the return value of `scanf()` and its brethren. If input failed, `resp` would be non-initialized.

```
switch (resp[300])
```

This accesses the **301st** element of `resp` (as numbering starts with 0). This element does not exist, the access is undefined behavior. If you would want the last element of the array, you'd use `resp[299]`, but that isn't what you want either. If you'd want the last character of the *string*, you'd use `resp[ strlen( resp ) - 1 ]`, but that isn't what you want either.

What you *actually want* is the *first* character, which is `resp[0]`.

```
case '6' ... '8':
```

This does not work at all unless what you're using is some kind of extended language; C does not have a `...` operator.

```
case 10:
```

This does not do what you think it does. Instead it compares a character's *binary* representation with the *value* 10. In ASCII, that would be the line feed.

All in all, the strong suggestion regarding user input is to use `fgets()` to read *whole lines* of input, and then parse them in memory (e.g. using `strtol()`, `strcmp()` or similar). Using `*scanf()` on potentially malformed user input is *strongly* discouraged; `*scanf()` is meant to read *known good* data, and its abilities to recover from error gracefully are limited. And `switch` is for distinct values. It does not work for ranges, and it is rather inadequate for working with strings in general.

Answer (score 1):

getting some feedback from all you guys, and doing some research i made a rather simple solution to my problem in the following way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {

    char resp[30];
    int i;
    
    
    printf ("Inform the letter of the class\nOr the age of the student\n");
    scanf(" %s", resp);
    
    for (i = 0; resp[i] != '\0'; i++) { 
        if (!isalpha(resp[i])) { 
            break; 
        }
    }
    
    if (resp[i] != '\0') {//if the value of [i] is different of null the result must be in the range of a char.
        int num = atoi(resp);//then i convert the string number to a int num
        
        switch (num){
        
        case 4:    
        case 5:
        printf ("\nFor the students in the age %i\nThe class will be A.", num);   
        break;
        
        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 8:
        printf ("\nFor the students in the age %i\nThe class will be B.", num);
        break;
        
        case 9:
        case 10:
        printf ("\nFor the students in the age %i\nThe class will be C.", num);
        break;
        
        default:
        printf ("\nWe are out of class\nFor students below 4 yo\nOr more than 10yo.");
        break;
        
        }
    
    }
    else {//if the value [i] is null the result must be a char.
        
        switch (resp[0]){
            
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
        printf ("\nFor students in the class A\nThe age range is between 4~5 years.");
        break;
        
        case 'b':
        case 'B':
        printf ("\nFor students in the class B\nThe age range is between 6~8 years.");
        break;
        
        case 'c':
        case 'C':
        printf ("\nFor students in the class C\nThe age range is between 9~10 years.");
        break;
        
        default:
        printf ("\nInvalid Class.");
    
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You still should indent your code properly.

Comment: `scanf` can still overflow. -- That first loop looks odd, and results in input like "A9" being interpreted as "9". Is that really what you want? Why not `isalpha( resp[0] )` and always act on the first information given instead of "the letter unless followed by a number"?

Answer (score 0):

One of the other answers has already listed and explained the errors in your code.

Therefore, in this answer, I will only show you the code for how I would solve the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//forward declarations
void get_line_from_user( const char prompt[], char buffer[], int buffer_size );
bool convert_string_to_long( char str[], long *num );

int main( void )
{
    //repeat until input is valid
    for (;;)
    {
        char input[300];
        long num;

        //get input from user
        get_line_from_user(
            "Please enter the letter of the class or the age of the student: ",
            input, sizeof input
        );

        //determine whether the user entered an integer
        if ( convert_string_to_long( input, &num ) )
        {
            switch( num )
            {
                case 4:
                case 5:
                    printf( "For the students of the age %ld, the class will be A.", num );
                    break;
                case 6:
                case 7:
                case 8:
                    printf( "For the students of the age %ld, the class will be B.", num );
                    break;
                case 9:
                case 10:
                    printf( "For the students of the age %ld, the class will be C.", num );
                    break;
                default:
                    printf( "Invalid age! It must be between 4 and 10!\n" );
                    continue;
            }

            //input was ok, so break out of infinite loop
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if ( input[0] == '\0' )
            {
                //input is empty, so reprompt user for input without
                //printing an error message
                continue;
            }
            if ( input[1] != '\0' )
            {
                //make sure that there are no further characters
                //after the first one, or that all superfluous
                //characters are whitespace characters
                for ( int i = 1; input[i] != '\0'; i++ )
                {
                    if ( !isspace( (unsigned char)input[i] ) )
                    {
                        printf( "Input must be an integer or a single letter!\n" );

                        //we cannot use "continue" here, because
                        //that would go to the next iteration of the
                        //inner loop, but we want to instead go to
                        //the next iteration of the outer loop
                        goto continue_outer_loop;
                    }
                }

                //the following block is only intended as a goto
                //target for jumping out of the nested loop
                if ( false )
                {
continue_outer_loop:
                    continue;
                }
            }

            switch ( toupper( (unsigned char)input[0] ) )
            {
                case 'A':
                    printf ("For students in class A, the age range is between 4-5 years.");
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    printf ("For students in class B, the age range is between 6-8 years.");
                    break;
                case 'C':
                    printf ("For students in class C, the age range is between 9-10 years.");
                    break;
                default:
                    printf( "Invalid letter!\n" );
                    continue;
            }
        }

        //input was ok, so break out of the infinite loop
        break;
    }
    
    return 0;
}

//This function will return true if the entire string was
//successfully converted to a long integer, otherwise it will
//return false.
bool convert_string_to_long( char str[], long *num )
{
    long result;
    char *p;

    //attempt to convert string to number
    result = strtol( str, &p, 10 );
    if ( p == str )
    {
        return false;
    }

    //verify that there are no unconverted characters, or that if
    //such characters do exist, that they are all whitespace
    //characters
    for ( ; *p != '\0'; p++ )
    {
        if ( !isspace( (unsigned char)*p ) )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //everything went ok, so pass the result
    *num = result;
    return true;
}

//This function will read exactly one line of input from the
//user. It will remove the newline character, if it exists. If
//the line is too long to fit in the buffer, then the function
//will automatically reprompt the user for input. On failure,
//the function will never return, but will print an error
//message and call "exit" instead.
void get_line_from_user( const char prompt[], char buffer[], int buffer_size )
{
    for (;;) //infinite loop, equivalent to while(1)
    {
        char *p;

        //prompt user for input
        fputs( prompt, stdout );

        //attempt to read one line of input
        if ( fgets( buffer, buffer_size, stdin ) == NULL )
        {
            printf( "Error reading from input!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //attempt to find newline character
        p = strchr( buffer, '\n' );

        //make sure that entire line was read in (i.e. that
        //the buffer was not too small to store the entire line)
        if ( p == NULL )
        {
            int c;

            //a missing newline character is ok if the next
            //character is a newline character or if we have
            //reached end-of-file (for example if the input is
            //being piped from a file or if the user enters
            //end-of-file in the terminal itself)
            if ( (c=getchar()) != '\n' && !feof(stdin) )
            {
                if ( ferror(stdin) )
                {
                    printf( "Error reading from input!\n" );
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }

                printf( "Input was too long to fit in buffer!\n" );

                //discard remainder of line
                do
                {
                    c = getchar();

                    if ( ferror(stdin) )
                    {
                        printf( "Error reading from input!\n" );
                        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                    }

                } while ( c != '\n' && c != EOF );

                //reprompt user for input by restarting loop
                continue;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //remove newline character by overwriting it with
            //null character
            *p = '\0';
        }

        //input was ok, so break out of loop
        break;
    }
}
```

This program has the following behavior:

```
Please enter the letter of the class or the age of the student: abc
Input must be an integer or a single letter!
Please enter the letter of the class or the age of the student: 6abc
Input must be an integer or a single letter!
Please enter the letter of the class or the age of the student: 3
Invalid age! It must be between 4 and 10!
Please enter the letter of the class or the age of the student: 4
For the students of the age 4, the class will be A.
```

```
Please enter the letter of the class or the age of the student: d
Invalid letter!
Please enter the letter of the class or the age of the student: b
For students in class B, the age range is between 6-8 years.
```

As you can see, I have designed the program in such a way that it will check whether the input is valid, and if not, it will automatically reprompt the user for new input.